A Women Being Eaten By a Man With Bat Wings from a movie or tv show in 90's or early 2000's?
I have been looking for this clip from a film or tv show.
It looks like it might take place in the 90"s or early 2000's; however,I am not one hundred percent sure. The movie or tv show looks from America or Canada. I know it is a movie or tv show and looks to take place in an RV. However, it could take place in a house or mobile home. It might be a B-movie. 
A man and woman look like they're going to have sex. She is in her underwear and never goes nude. The man looks at her and woman says "Don't you want me." I believe she is a high school student or just got out of school. I think the man face changes and bat-wings surround the woman. She is killed or eaten. This is not from Jeepers Creepers. I thought maybe it is from Buffy The Vampire Slayer or Angel. I think scene ends with the woman be stripped to the bone. Does anyone know where this scene takes place? I saw this video on youtube between 2006-2011.

I found something about a creature that does what you explain... Just have to find the movie, if this looks familiar...

Not that is not it. It takes place in the 90's and a creature is a man. I think his face changes and she gets eaten. He could be a vampire or something else. Both man and woman are in their underwear. I pretty sure batwings surround her. But, not 100% sure now.
